# Go believes variables inside conditional statements are unused?

Tags: go, unused-variables

I have a situation where if something fails to assign a variable I instead assign it within a conditional statement however Go seems to think this variable is unused.

```golang
        for index, value := range group.Values {
            timestamp, err := time.Parse(time.RFC3339, value.Timestamp)
            if err != nil {
                strings.ReplaceAll(value.Timestamp, "+0000", "")
                timestamp, err := time.Parse(time.RFC3339, value.Timestamp)
                if err != nil {
                    log.Printf("Error parsing timestamp for point %s: (%s) %v", value.Context+"_"+value.ID, value.Timestamp, err)
                    continue
                }
            }
            event := new(SplunkEvent)
            event.Time = timestamp.Unix()
```

Go believes the variable `timestamp` inside the conditional statement is unused. Why is that? I have clearly used it directly after the condition.

Comment: The `timestamp` variable declared inside the if statement is not used.  Fix by changing the [short variable declaration](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Short_variable_declarations) inside the if statement to [assignment](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Assignments): `timestamp, err = time.Parse(time.RFC3339, value.Timestamp)`

Comment: Ahhhhh it has to be in the same block to be allowed to do a redeclaration. That's what I missed

Answer (score 2):

The nested (inner) `timestamp` declaration shadows the outer one - so the outer one is never set. So since the inner value is never used, the compilation error is valid.

To fix, replace `:=` declared assignment operator with `=` to (re)use the outer scope's `timestamp` (and `err`) values:

```
timestamp, err = time.Parse(time.RFC3339, value.Timestamp)
```

Comment: I wasn't able to suggest an edit because the queue was full, but as a novice go programmer I didn't understand that you *can* use a short variable declaration to redeclare a variable but it must be the *same block*. It's that last part that confused me